# Replace reference with its value in Excel VBA workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook to manage my Delivery Notes, which creates another workbook with actual delivery note and stores it in the folder for me, then places new record in my main workbook so that the Delivery Number for the next delivery note can be increased by 1.

My main problem is, when I create new Delivery note I can select if there is any additional address for Invoicing purpose and if there is not one then it will not show on the delivery note, this done with conditional formatting that takes value 1 or 2 from the Named Range `DelAddress`. The problem is that the value in the Named Range `DelAddress` on the Delivery notes saved as separate files is still referencing my Main Workbook `='[may-main-workbook.xlsm]Manager'!$E$17`.

What should I do to change this to a value instead of the reference?

I have tried the following but it has not worked:

```
    newBook.Activate
    newSheet.Activate    
If NameExists(newSheet, "DelAddress") Then
        newSheet.Range("DelAddress").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
    End If
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-assign a cell's value to itself in VBA to overwrite the formula/link with the actual value.

```
If NameExists(newSheet, "DelAddress") Then
    With newSheet.Range("DelAddress")
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, but it did not work for some reason

Comment: Try going to Data -> Edit Links and then break the links to the other workbook first.

Comment: I am not sure how, because the value 'DelAddress' is only used in the conditional formatting and does not really exist anywhere on the new sheet except as as a named range